# Tikz-UML include and extend not compiling

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

For some strange reason `\umlinclude` and `\umlextend` are not compiling..

I've been trying to fix this problem for quite some time, without any success. Also couldn't  find anything on the internet.. So I figured I'd ask here.

Here is the minimal not working example:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlsystem}[x=4, fill=gray!10]{System}

\umlusecase[name=case-1]{Case 1}
\umlusecase[x=2, y=-2, name=case-2]{Case 2}
\umlusecase[x=-2, y=-2, name=case-3]{Case 3}

\umlextend{case-1}{case-2}
\umlinclude{case-2}{case-3}

\end{umlsystem}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Produces the error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\save@sf@q #1->\leavevmode \begingroup \edef \@SF 
                                                  {\spacefactor \the \spacef...
l.17 \umlextend{case-1}{case-2}

? 
! Emergency stop.
\save@sf@q #1->\leavevmode \begingroup \edef \@SF 
                                                  {\spacefactor \the \spacef...
l.17 \umlextend{case-1}{case-2}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on uml-test.log.
```

Which leaves me clueless..

Please help!

Comment: Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. `tikz-uml` uses `\guillemotleft` in its code in a place where it breaks if the OT1-definition is active. Make also a bug report.

Comment: You sir, are awesome! :D Thanks, and will do.

Comment: I'm not a sir, I'm a woman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ulrike Fischer stated, adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I defined << and >> with `$\ll$` and `$\gg$`instead of `\guillemotleft`and `\guillemotright` so that next release of tikz-uml, available soon, does not depend anymore on `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`